# The observation returned by the `reset()` method is not contained with the observation space

Tags: deep-learning, openai-gym

i'm strugling to understand how custom observation_space should be coded and how there isn't so much info about some topics i have to ask here

if for example i have to return a observation with an array of 6 numeric values:

```
def __init__(self): # from my CustomEnv class
   self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)
   
   self.observation_space = spaces.Box(0,1, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)

def reset(self):
    return self._next_observation(self)

def _next_observation(self):
    obs = np.array([0.098231, 0.098231, 0.098231, 0.098231, 0.098231, 231])
    return obs
```

When i procceed to test the Agent:

```
import gym
import envs
...
env = gym.make('CustomEnv-v0')
    
state = selv.env.reset() #this particular line
```

my terminal throws:

```
/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py", line 115, in _check_obs
), f"{pre} is not contained with the observation space ({observation_space})"

AssertionError: The observation returned by the `reset()` method is not contained with the observation space (Box(0.0, 1.0, (1,), float32))
```

Answer (score 1):

The observation space size should be the same for both self.observation_space, and the return value in reset. It looks like the observation space is only being defined as 1 element. What I think you'd want instead is

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(6,), dtype=np.float32)
```

Further the first two values in box are low and high, so your final return value `231` appears to be out of bounds. It's probably the next error you'd get.

What you can do there is set the low and high values to be different for each space by passing in a numpy array to low and high where each element of the array represents the corresponding element of the Box space you want to use.